# Как создать dll?

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер - установил visual studio 2017 почти со всеми дополнениями:Не ставил Node и ASP.
Подскажите как мне создать dll для C++?Не могу найти Win32 вкладку как в гайде на сайте майкрософт[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может другие типы проектов?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka там только Новое решение

Comment: В MSDN человек пожаловался, что трудно найти, ему сказали "это не баг, а фича".
I found the possibility when I selected Windows Desktop Wizard.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Выбирайте консольное приложение, там откроется мастер создания - установите "Тип приложеня" как DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Если нет мастера (а в VC 17 такое присутствует иногда), создайте пустой проект, и в свойствах выберите тип dll.